# Is there a way to derive the ideal gas law from statistical mechanics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

If notions of thermodynamics emerge from statistical mechanics, is there a way to derive the ideal gas law?

And this derivation would be more "fundamental"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are several. Check the last section of this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law#Statistical_mechanics_2), where it is derived from the equipartition theorem. Another way would be through the partition function and computing quantities associated with it, such as [internal energy, pressure, etc](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/lectures/node65.html).

The derivation from statistical mechanics is more fundamental inasmuch as you start with fundamental laws, not by phenomenological ones as it's done in thermodynamics.

Answer (score 3):

[A derivation](http://people.physik.hu-berlin.de/~sokolov/Macrosci/Lecture0.pdf) I enjoy for how fundamental it is but didn't find anywhere else is based on combinatorics:

Say there are N particles which can be placed in a volume-lattice. The volume-lattice has cubic cells of side $a$. There are $M= \frac{V}{a^3}$ cells. Since we may assume particles are point-like and the cells are not, we can place particles into cells which are already occupied. Therefore, there are $W=M^N$ ways to spread $N$ distinguishable particles over $M$ cells.

Free energy is given by:
$$F = const - T S$$
Pressure is given by:
$$p = - \frac{\partial F}{\partial V}$$
Entropy is given by:
$$S = k_B \ln(W) = k_B \ln(M)*N = k_B N (\ln V-3 \ln a)$$
Putting it all together:
$$p = - \frac{\partial F}{\partial V} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial V} const + T k_B N \frac{\partial}{\partial V}(\ln V) - T k_B N \frac{\partial}{\partial V}(3 \ln a)$$
Only terms containing $V$ survive, resulting in:
$$p = T k_B N \frac{\partial}{\partial V}(\ln V) = T k_B \frac{N}{V}$$

I believe this to be the most fundamental derivation, since it makes no assumption on particle properties, momentum, grid layout or even dimension. One could just as easily derive "one-dimensional pressure" this way.

---

Technicality: I assumed particles may be distinguished. Usually, they are assumed to be indistinguishable. This would result in $W=\frac{M^N}{N!}$. However, the derivation wouldn't change, since this would just add another $V$-independent term "$-\ln(N!)$". This factor is called [Gibbs factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox), resolving Gibbs' mixing paradox.